# Short story about a doctor who is a werewolf

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, werewolf

This short story involved a doctor werewolf who ended up being cured of his lycanthropy by being shrunk and placed inside his own body (or a robot version of it maybe? cloned?) based on the premise that the moon would never be visible to trigger a transformation.